# Bash: what is the meaning of ${parameter##word}

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm working on bash code and I found a function `CheckOtherFiles` that I guess is used to check if a file (`$1`) is more recent from file `$WS_ROOT/$NomeVista/COMP/COMP_COMPILE`.

`CheckOtherFiles` is called with one parameter that is a file with absolute path.

Here is the code:

```
function CheckOtherFiles {
   fver=$1
   if [[ -r $fver ]]
   then
      if [[ -r $WS_ROOT/$NomeVista/COMP/COMP_COMPILE ]]
      then
         filecheck=`/bin/ls -1t $fver $WS_ROOT/$NomeVista/COMP/COMP_COMPILE | head -1`
         if [[ ${filecheck##*/} = ${fver##*/} ]]
         then
            return 1
         fi
      fi
   fi
   return 0
}
```

I read bash manual and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059794/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-0-syntax-with-variable-braces-and-hash-chara) useful link, but it is unclear the meaning of:

```
   if [[ ${filecheck##*/} = ${fver##*/} ]]
```

I also doubt that there is an error in it.

So, could you please help me understanding the meaning of this piece of code?

Also I really appreciate any suggestion to improve this function.

Comment: It's substring removal: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html Looks like an alternate way of doing `basename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the linked question, this is [substring removal](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
${string##substring}
   Deletes longest match of $substring from front of $string.
```

In this case, it is removing the path and retaining only the [`basename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/basename):

```
$ FILE=/etc/default/google-chrome
$ echo ${FILE##*/}
google-chrome
$ basename $FILE
google-chrome
```

Ordinarily, I'd stick to `basename`, but it's a matter of opinion whether write-only code is better if it is faster. At any rate, I don't see an error in it.

However, you could consider the [`-nt` and `-ot` tests](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html):

```
f1 -nt f2
   file f1 is newer than f2

f1 -ot f2
   file f1 is older than f2
```

And perhaps simplify it to:

```
other_file="$WS_ROOT/$NomeVista/COMP/COMP_COMPILE"
if [[ -r $fver && -r $other_file && ( $fver -nt $otherfile ) ]]
then
    return 1
fi
return 0
```

Comment: Good! thanks. Only one question: my doubt on `if` statement is about single `=`, I wonder if it is always true or always false.

Comment: @Letizia `=` and `==` are synonyms in `bash`. `=` is POSIX, and `==` doesn't have any advantages.

Comment: @Letizia Oh, I see. If `$fver` is `/some/path/COMP_COMPILE`, the function will always return 1. I don't know if that's a bug or a feature.

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes, now it is clear and I have to find out where and how this function is used to know if it is bug or features. Thanks.